# Windows library inclusion in CMake Project

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, cross-platform

I have a growing project in CMake.  It is time to link to a library, which at this time exists only in Windows,  Linux functionality will have to wait.  I am attempting to do this with preprocessor directives as recommended in an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674939/cross-platform-dynamic-linking-windows-to-linux):

```
// MyLibHeader.hpp
#ifdef WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#define ProcHandle HINSTANCE 
#define LoadLib LoadLibraryA
#define LoadSym GetProcAddress
#else
// ... I'll fill these in with dlopen etc. when necessary
```

This is the first platform specific inclusion I have had to put in my code, and It seems there is more to it than this.  This is generating this error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\include\intrin.h(944) : error C2733: second C linkage of overloaded function '_interlockedbittestandset' not allowed

The error is repeated four times, twice in intrin.h, and twice in winnt.h.  So here's my question.  Are there other includes or preprocessor steps I need to take to get this to work inside windows (up to now it has been a basic console application)  and is there something in CMake I can leverage to make this easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've been able to scrape up with some help and some google, one solution is indeed to comment out the duplicate definitions of `_interlockedbittestandset` in `initrin.h`

This may have been fixed in later versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: I must say, I find myself averse to such hackery.

Comment: That hackery was indeed successful.

Comment: One such discussion is cataloged here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcprerelease/thread/61b5becd-90f9-40a4-b545-5f171fe45daa

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the source code of CMake, there is a C++ class that does cross platform library loading.  It is a BSD style license so you could just copy the code.  Works on lots of platforms.  The code is here:

http://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=blob;f=Source/kwsys/DynamicLoader.cxx;h=c4ee095519fe27742a0a9a9e392be4ce095af423;hb=HEAD